# How to install Matplotlib on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I have tried installing Python Matplotlib in different ways on my Windows 7, like:

```
$ pip install matplotlib
```

and

```
$ easy_install matplotlib
```

But whenever I run my Python program, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

What is the best way to install Python modules on Windows 7?

Comment: What is the console output when you type `pip install matplotlib`? Did you type that into your command line shell or the python shell (that won't work)?

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7, python 2.7

Comment: pip install matplotlib

Comment: We can see *what* you typed. We need to know *where* you did that and what the output was that you got from it.

Comment: Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-1.5.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ===========================================================================

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.5.3]
                    python: yes [2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015,
                            20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

Comment: * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\dtmarti
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qthkyi\matplotlib
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' com
and.

Comment: did you tried to upgrade pip as suggested? "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"
also did you installed all the dependencies: 
"For standard Python installations you will also need to install compatible versions of setuptools, numpy, python-dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, and cycler in addition to matplotlib."

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: great! i've added it as an awnser, mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to upgrade pip as suggested:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Also did you installed all the dependencies:

"For standard Python installations you will also need to install compatible versions of setuptools, numpy, python-dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, and cycler in addition to matplotlib."

Answer (score 0):

Simply download IPython with the Anaconda Suite....
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

It brings most of the needed modules (as this is a crappy task if you have to download stuff to `site-packages` and run `python setup.py install` 3781 times..)

Moreover it sports module package manager (comparable to Synaptic on Ubuntu..) if you are to lazy for the above mentioned task (and you are..).

Greets Dr. Cobra

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install matplotlib

conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib

pip install matplotlib
```